# Can anybody explain what is BreadCrumb in DNN ?

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke

I am new to DNN
Can anybody explain  what is BreadCrumb in DNN ? 
I need to understand this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of a web site a breadcrumb is some way to show your current position within the navigation hierarchy of the web site. This can be used when the web site has a hierarchical navigation structure. Here is an example of a breadcrumb that could be displayed on the top of a page:

> Front page > About > Contact > Detailed map

One explanation of this odd metaphor is that it is inspired from the fairy tale [Hansel and Gretel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_and_Gretel) where the two children Hansel and Gretel are kidnapped into the woods but manages to escape because they have left a breadcrumb trail allowing them to find their way home. Actually, the fairy tale is a bit more complicated but I will not get into the details here.

Comment: thank you so much Martin. :)